# Xcode Release Configuration Testing

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, release

I have an issue with my app when I set my build to a release configuration scheme. One of the sound effects that the app uses plays fine in the debug configuration, but not in the release config. How can I get feedback from the app in this "mode"? In the debug config you can obviously use `NSLog` or set breakpoints. Any ideas?

**Edit**

The overall issue is that in the debug configuration, the plist is read in both of the methods listed below. In the release configuration, the plist is only read in one of the methods below.

Here's the code for loading the files. Only the first few lines matter. The `NSString *audioInfoPList` is nil for `initSfx:` but not for `initMusic:

```
-(void) initMusic {
    _musicDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    NSString *audioInfoPList = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"AudioInfo" ofType: @"plist"];
    NSDictionary *audioInfoData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:audioInfoPList];

    //more processing here
    ...
}


-(void) initSfx {
    _sfxDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    NSString *audioInfoPList = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"AudioInfo" ofType: @"plist"];
    NSDictionary *audioInfoData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:audioInfoPList];

    //more processing here
    ...
}
```

Here's `AudioInfo.plist`:

[image: AudioInfo.plist]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been resolved. It seems that when searching for a file in a bundle of a project that has a space in the name it doesn't always find the file. I renamed my project without spaces and it worked fine. Does anybody know why this occurs?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the problem by `NSLog` too.

Step:
1. connect your device to your mac. 
2. Xcode Window -> Devices -> Choose your device, then you can see all console log in here. 
(Maybe console is hidden, click the lower left corner icon to make it expand)

Maybe the problem is file path problem. You can console out the effect file path to check it.

In addition, Debug Configuration and Release Configuration are build config options, which can't stop your debugger connector. Debugger is working determined by your developer certificate. (I assume that you have configured the Adhoc or Appstore certificate)

I hope this useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Yeah, I'm definitely having some sort of file path problem. `methodA:` in  `classA` has no problems opening a plist file, but `methodB:` from the same class doesn't open it. It returns nil. It's so weird. When I run it in the debug configuration it's fine, but the release config doesn't work properly. You said `Maybe the problem is file path problem. You can console out the effect file path to check it.` what did you mean by that?

Comment: use ``NSLog`` to check problem. Print Path (check path) and print File Object(check nil). You can see log by the Device Console (Window -> Devices). Different build model will create different app file path. Maybe your file path is an absolute path(Not sure). Post your load file code could help to location the problem.

Comment: Yeah, you were right, the console works with no problems. There is just no reason why the plist loads in one method, but not in the other. I've checked for spelling mistakes...it's very confusing.

Comment: Go to Project "Build Phases" -> "Copy Bundle Resources", check AudioInfo.plist inside of "Copy Bundle Resources"(Check each Project if your workspace has more than one Project). Try to remove and re-add AudioInfo.plist if the file inside of "Copy Bundle Resources".

Comment: Yeah I tried all that. Remember, I'm talking about one project and one class with two methods that try to open this plist file. One is successful and the other is not.